# subsets in general position in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

> A subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is said to be in **general position** if no
>   three of its points are collinear. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains
>   a dense subset in general position. Extend the definition and the
>   result to higher dimensional Euclidean spaces.

We know that there always exists an irrational number in between two rational numbers. So if we take a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two vertices with rational coordinates and the third vertex with irrational coordinate (or two with irrationals and one with rationals), then this set is dense and fulfills the required criteria. But if we extend this to higher dimensional analogue, such as a tetrahedron or a cube in three dimension, with vertices suitably chosen, are they correct examples in higher dimensional spaces as above? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A triangle is not in general position, nor is it dense in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Is that exercise 3.3 from the "Introduction to General Topology" by K. D. Joshi? Because there's a very important hint there: take a countable dense subset $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and then choose $b_n$ inductively such that $d(a_n,b_n)<1/n$ and $b_n$ is not collinear with any pair from $\{b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1}\}$. Then $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the set you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q_n, n \in \Bbb N$ be a dense set of $\Bbb R^2$. (e.g. the points with two rational coordinates, in some enumeration).

Pick, by recursion, $r_n \in \Bbb R^2$ such that at each stage $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

1. $d(q_n, r_n) < \frac{1}{n}$.
2. $r_n$ is not collinear with any pair from $\{r_1, r_2, , \ldots, r_{n-1}\}$.

For $n=1$, we can just pick $r_1=q_1$ as condition 2 is void for $n=1$.

At stage $n\ge 2$, we already have $r_1,\ldots , r_{n-1}$ and these determine finitely many lines by taking pairs from them, and these lines together are nowhere dense; i.e. the interior of the union is empty, which implies that the open ball around $q_n$ of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ cannot be covered by these lines, i.e. we can pick $r_n$ in that ball but not on any of these lines, and this allows us to carry on.

After the recursion we have a countable set that is dense:if $x \in \Bbb R^2$ then there is a sequence of all distinct points $q_{n_m}$ that converges to $x$, and the corresponding sequence from the $r_n$ then also converges to $x$, using 1.
It is also in general position, because if $r_{n_1}, r_{n_2}, r_{n_3}$ are on a line, say with $n_1 < n_2 < n_3$ WLOG, then we could not have added $r_{n_3}$ at stage $n_3$, because we chose it not to be on (among others) the line through $r_{n_1}$ and $r_{n_2}$, so it contradicts our construction demands so it cannot happen.